# icudt error while installing stringi package from r in linux offline

Tags: linux, redhat, offline, stringi, installation-package

I have downloaded stringi_1.4.3.tar.gz package in my System (RedHat Linux 7), but when I am trying to install offline it I am getting error as below:

> Execution halted
>   *** icudt download failed. stopping.
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’

This is a new environment `RedHatLinux 7.x`, R version is 3.6, here I am doing a testing for offline installation of R set up and the R packages, wherein I encountered this error.

I have already tried downloading older version of `stringi`, but it didn't work.

> checking with pkg-config for the system ICU4C... 50.1.2
>   checking for ICU4C >= 52... no
>   *** ICU4C 50.1.2 has been detected**
>    Minimal requirements, i.e., ICU4C >= 52, are not met
>    **Trying with "standard" fallback flags
>   checking whether we may build an ICU4C-based project... yes
>   checking programmatically for sufficient U_ICU_VERSION_MAJOR_NUM... no
>   *** The available ICU4C cannot be used
>   checking whether we may compile src/icu61/common/putil.cpp... yes
>   checking whether we may compile src/icu61/i18n/number_affixutils.cpp... yes
>   checking whether we can fetch icudt... downloading the ICU data library (icudt)
>   output path: icu61/data/icudt61l.zip
>   trying URL 'http://www.ibspan.waw.pl/~gagolews/stringi/icudt61l.zip'
>   Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL XXX
>
> trying URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu61/data/icudt61l.zip'
>   Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL XXX
>
> trying URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu55/data/icudt61l.zip'
>   Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL XXX
>
> trying URL 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu61/data/icudt61l.zip'
>   Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL XXX
>
> trying URL 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu55/data/icudt61l.zip'
>   Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL XXX
>
> trying URL 'http://www.gagolewski.com/software/stringi/icudt61l.zip'
>   Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL XXX
>
> icudt download failed
>   Error: Stopping on error
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb") :
>      XXX status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
>   2: In download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb") :
>     URL XXX status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
>   3: In download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb") :
>     URL XXX status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
>   4: In download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb") :
>     URL XXX  status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
>   5: In download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb") :
>     URL XXX status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
>   6: In download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb") :
>     URL XXX status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
>   Execution halted
>   *** icudt download failed. stopping.
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
>   * removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/stringi’

I downloaded and installed it on windows 10, there ii worked as expected.I want stringi package because it has dependency on other packages.Please Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was exactly in the same case and just got finally done installing that package. 
I went to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/INSTALL and scrolled a little bit to find an answer. I'm quoting :

"If you have **absolutely no internet access** on the machines
you try to install `stringi` on, try fetching the latest development version
of the package. It already includes the `ICU` data archives.
You can build a distributable source package that includes all the required
ICU data files (for off-line use) by omitting some relevant lines in
the `.Rbuildignore` file. The following command sequence should do the trick:

```
wget https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/archive/master.zip -O stringi.zip
unzip stringi.zip
sed -i '/\/icu..\/data/d' stringi-master/.Rbuildignore
R CMD build stringi-master
```

Assuming the most recent development version is 1.3.1,
a file named `stringi_1.3.1.tar.gz` is created in the current working directory.
The package can now be installed (the source bundle may be propagated via
`scp` etc.) by executing:

```
R CMD INSTALL stringi_1.3.1.tar.gz
```

or by calling `install.packages("stringi_1.3.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL)`,
from within an R session."

For the wget part, i just had to download directly from the link and send it to my server and then i got straight to the unzip-ing :)

Comment: I got:
$ sed -i '/\/icu..\/data/d' stringi-master/.Rbuildignore
sed: 1: "stringi-master/.Rbuildi ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression

Comment: [This link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62h) fixed my issue, I'm using BSD tools on Mac, so sed is different

Comment: Hello, I am using Windows to build stringi. Can you please share what the get-content PowerShell command would be to replace text in the .Rbuildignore file? I am not familiar with Regex in Unix. This command seemed to fail: `get-content stringi-master/.Rbuildignore | %{$_ -replace "/\/icu..\","/data/d"}`