# install stringi on centos 7 without Internet

Tags: r, gcc, centos7, stringi

I have apparently the common problem to install `stringe` on a Centos CentOS 7.9 without Internet I have just a remote to Cran. It means I have 'stringi_1.5.3.tar.gz'
After unziping I get:
[image: stringi-folder after unzip]

I get the following error

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking with pkg-config for the system ICU4C... 50.2
checking for ICU4C >= 55... no
*** ICU4C 50.2 has been detected
*** Minimal requirements, i.e., ICU4C >= 55, are not met
*** Trying with "standard" fallback flags
checking whether we may build an ICU4C-based project... yes
checking programmatically for sufficient U_ICU_VERSION_MAJOR_NUM... no
*** The available ICU4C cannot be used
checking whether we may compile src/icu61/common/putil.cpp... yes
checking whether we may compile src/icu61/i18n/number_affixutils.cpp... yes
checking whether we can fetch icudt... downloading the ICU data library (icudt)
output path: icu61/data/icudt61l.zip
trying URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu61/data/icudt61l.zip'
Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gagolews/stringi/master/src/icu61/data/icudt61l.zip'
```

The Problem is well known:

[icudt error while installing stringi package from r in linux offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880786/icudt-error-while-installing-stringi-package-from-r-in-linux-offline)

[How to install stringi from local file (ABSOLUTELY no Internet Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942322/how-to-install-stringi-from-local-file-absolutely-no-internet-access)

or

[Installing stringi](https://stringi.gagolewski.com/install.html)

I tried all up to

```
sed -i '/\/icu..\/data/d' stringi-master/.Rbuildignore
```

there is no `.Rbuildignore` see the pic of directory!

Any idea how can I solve the problem?

More precise question:
How can I change the setting `mode="wb"` ?

```
Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), icudtzipfname, mode = "wb")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `tar -zxf stringi_1.5.3.tar.gz` and then you will have to CD into the unzipped file and do
./configure
make
sudo make install

Comment: The same error:  '*** icudt download failed. stopping.'